# Is "a" in $2^n$-a **two's complement of a relative to a fixed bit length n** decimal number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Definition : Given a positive integer a, the **two's complement of a relative to a fixed bit length n** is the n-bit binary representation of $2^n$-a

Bit lengths of 16 and 32 are the mostly used in practice. However, because the principles are the same for all bit lengths, we use a bit length of 8 for simplicity in this discussion. For instance, because

($2^8-27)_{10} = (256-27)_{10} = 229_{10} = (128 +64+32+4+1)_{10} = 11100101_{2}$.

the 8-bit two's complement of 27 is $11100101_2$.

Source: Discrete Mathematics with Applications by Susanna Epp, p. 84

Comment: Unclear question.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Since $2^n$ is a decimal representation and not a binary, one might think so...

Comment: Being "a decimal number" is not an inherent property of a number. A number can be written written down in different systems of notations, but it is _the same number_ no matter how you choose to write it down (or even if you don't plan on writing it down at all). So asking whether $a$ is a decimal number in this definition does not make sense.

Comment: @NeinDochOah Oh I was completely disregarding $2^n$ is a decimal representation, then I understand that $a$ in $2^n-a$ is also a decimal number.

Comment: It's a number. How it is represented is irrelevant. $2^n-a$ is still defined the same.

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice that the question was edited.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I see then, $a$ can be also quinary number octal number or the others as well as decimal. Right?

Comment: There are no octal numbers. There are octal representations (names) for numbers. Treating $10_{10}$ and $101_3$ as "different" is like treating the german number "drei" as different from "three." They are different ways of naming the same thing.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew Okay, I see. a number in binary notation, in decimal notation, in octal notaion, ...

Comment: Yes. We obviously prefer consistency - trying to work with $101_7-111111_2 +LVI_{\text{roman}}$ is going to make the head spin. But we can compute it - what notation we use to write the result in is unclear. :)

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't really relevant. $a$ denotes an integer number independently of its literal representation.

$2^n$ is indeed mot probably decimal (it can't be binary and there's no reason to silently use octal, hex or another).

Anyway, provided the basis are unambiguous, you can mix the genres

$$256_d-AB_h=2_d^8-10101011_b=100_h-171_d\cdots$$